# Firefox - How to disable auto-redirect, auto-refresh?

Tags: firefox, redirect, refresh

i am using newest version of Firefox.

I would like to block all auto-redirects and auto-refreshes, is it possible? I did not find anything similar in about:config.

Thanks in advance.